# Reading a file from Running other programs from Tcl

Tags: io, tcl

I am opening a shell program from tcl with open command, the shell output file has some stings and tcl commands line by line. Could any tell me how to print if the line is a list of strings and how to evaluate if the line is a tcl command

I used the following sytnax, but it is trying to excute the strings also,

```
set fileID [open "| unix ../filename_1" r+]
     while 1 {
     set line [gets $fileID]
     puts "Read line: $line"
     if {$line == "some_text"} { puts $line  #text
     } elseif { $line == "cmd"} {set j [eval $line] #eval cmd }
```

}

Answer (score 1):

You can try this (tested)

Principle : the first word of each line is tested to see if it belongs to the list of tcl commands, 
which has been first obtained by "info commands".

Sometimes you can not properly obtain the first word, that's why this command is in a catch {}.

```
set fileID [open myfile]
set cmdlist [info commands]
while {1} {
    set readLine [gets $fileID]
    if { [eof $fileID]} {
        break
    }
    catch {set firstword [lindex $readLine 0] }
    if { [lsearch $cmdlist $firstword] != -1 } {
        puts "tcl command line : $readLine"
    } else {
        puts "other line   : $readLine"
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Abenhurt,  the above code is working. I need print the lines in tcl first and then excute the tcl command.

Comment: +1. I had a few comments about your code, so I added a community wiki answer.

Answer (score 1):

Full credit to abendhurt. Rewriting his answer into more idiomatic Tcl:

```
set fid [open myfile]
set commands [info commands]
while {[gets $fid line] != -1} {
    set first [lindex [split $line] 0]
    if {$first in $commands} {
        puts "tcl command line : $line"
    } else {
        puts "other line   : $line"
    }
}
```

Notes:

- use `while {[gets ...] != -1}` to reduce the code a bit.
- use `split` to convert the string into a proper list -- no longer need `catch`
- use the builtin `in` operator to improve readability.

---

I think I understand:

```
set fid [openopen "| unix ../filename_1" r]
set commands [info commands]
set script [list]
while {[gets $fid line] != -1} {
    set first [lindex [split $line] 0]
    if {$first in $commands} {
        lappend script $line
    } 
    puts $line
}   
eval [join $script ;]
```

Comment: Thanks glen jackman, I needed the following waay ex: myfile may have lin1: AAAA lin2: BBBB lin3: cmd1 lin4: CCCC,,,,so on   print output::AAAA BBBB cmd1 CCCC,,,, after execute tcl_cmd:: eval cmd1

Comment: I don't understand. Lack of formatting in comments. Please update your question.

Comment: Input file (combination of strings and commands):

AAAA #text
BBBB  #text
cmd1  # eval tcl command
DDDD #text
cmd2
..... 

TCL output:
AAAA 
BBBB  
cmd1  
DDDD 
cmd2
....
eval:cmd1 
eval:cmd2
eval: ...